# Could pinging several IPs make my network busy?

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, ping

I developed an application that pings 60 IPs, but if I run it at home most of replies are 'request timed out', whereas if I do the same thing at work, 3 out of 4 replies are ok. I thought it was due to a structural difference between the 2 networks... Is there something I can do in order to improve things in general? I splitted the IPs into various threads (~5 for each thread) but when pinging at home the app seems to respond correctly only on the first and the last of the five. Can these operations hang up my network? Could it be the firewall?

Sorry for my english

**Edit: I forgot to say that IPs are public ones**

Comment: How are you pinging them? By starting the `ping` process or programatically?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which OS you use at each environment (home and work)?

Comment: You have to be careful with ICMP - no sockets, so it's quite possible that the gnip will be received by a different thread than the one that issued the ping.

Comment: How often are you pinging each host? Once a second?

Comment: I developed the application in C# and I'm pinging the IPs through the Ping.Send() method (2 nested cycles, one for packets and the other to scroll the IP-array), OSes are Windows 7 Pro (work)(if I remember correctly) and Windows 7 Home Premium (home).
@MartinJames if I lock the code that actually sends the icmp request ...?

    Joachim I ping each host with a timeout of 200 ms

Comment: **EDIT** Joachim: I ping each host with a timeout of 200 ms between packets; there are 5 packets to be sent so at most 1 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your network is slow for 5 pings per second because of internet connection, it looks your intranet is much more faster than your internet connection, maybe a gigabit bandwidth intranet.
try lowering ping frequency for example 1 per second or set timeout to 1000ms.

Comment: I wouldn't spend too much time to finish all the icmp reqs, but I'll take the idea in consideration

Comment: your process loop cant effect the result because it has to be really fast, effecting parameters are your bandwidth and if target host is busy or not. if your ips are in local network only effecting parameter is target host's reply rate. you can also use threads for pinging more than one ip at a time.

Comment: Ok so probably is too much work for my bandwidth.. So I think I have to focus on where my application will run (bandwidth). If I know that my app will run only on professional network (and it does) I can avoid wasting time trying to make it work also on home network, right?

Comment: that's right, but pinging so frequently is not needed in most applications i think.